# What is the fastest way to convert very large binary number representation to decimal representation?

Tags: c++, binary, decimal, biginteger

I've got very big number stored in binary representation and I need to output it in decimal representation:

```
struct BigInteger {
    int *parts; // one part stores 12 bits of number, range: 0 to 0xfff
    int parts_n;
};

void convertToDecString( BigInteger *in, std::string &out );
```

I can't find any approach, that would do it in linear time.

For demostration you can chose any order for parts. I've got it ordered in way, that [0] is lowest value, and [n-1] is the highest value.

Comment: I suggest using an existing *Big Number* library, as they have already debugged it.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it cannot be done in linear time, because every read bit affects all digits of the decimal representation. The longer the digit, the longer every new read bit takes.